# xcode 4.6.2 alert "Could not launch “TrackMix” Connection refused"when run cocoa aplication

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

When I try to run cocoa sample application "TrackMix" in xcode 4.6.2([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/GettingStarted.html)), it throws the alert:

```
Could not launch “TrackMix”
Connection refused
```

How could I resolve it.

Comment: Are you debugging the app?  Do you have `localhost` mapped to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: It's very nice of you trojanfoe~~thank you

Comment: What's very nice of me?

Comment: edit the etc/hosts

check if localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1

and thank trojanfoe